# Restoring a clean MSSQL 2005 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an MSSQL 2005 installation on a machine, and somehow it's *tempdb* files got deleted.

I don't really care about what was on there as I am cleaning the instance anyway and starting from scratch.

The problem is I can't get the server to start, and I can't find any documentation on how to restore the server.

Any pointers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the whole problem was solved by simply recreating the *tempdb* directory.

*tempdb* files are recreated on each server startup, so there's nothing really to recover, and the problem was that the directory was missing.